# Install GIMP's Felimage plugin

Tags: gimp, software-installation

I am following a tutorial and the step I'm at requires to apply a filter "[Felimage](http://fimg-gmplugins.sourceforge.net/)". However, I cannot install it. Running `./configure` says that I do not meet the GIMP version requirement :

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gimp-2.0 >= 2.2.0 gimpui-2.0 >= 2.2.0) were not met.
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively you may set the GIMP_CFLAGS and GIMP_LIBS environment variables
to avoid the need to call pkg-config.  See the pkg-config man page for
more details.
```

However, if I run `gimp --version`, I get the output

```
GNU Image Manipulation Program version 2.8.10
```

I tried installing GIMP's plugin registry package, but nothing useful there.

How can I install Felimage on Ubuntu 13.10?

#### ** Edit **

From the author, Guillermo :

> I see, try installing libgimp2.0-dev (and libglib2.0-dev if it isn't
>   there already) as well, and let me know if that doesn't fix the issue.

Thus, `sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev` later and `./configure` works.

However, `make` does not and fails with

```
gcc  -g -O2 -Wall   -o felimage-noise  basis.o cell_3d.o cell_4d.o cell_5d.o interface.o lnoise_3d.o lnoise_4d.o lnoise_5d.o loadconf.o main.o poisson.o random.o render.o saveconf.o snoise_3d.o snoise_4d.o snoise_5d.o -lgimpui-2.0 -lgimpwidgets-2.0 -lgimpmodule-2.0 -lgimp-2.0 -lgimpmath-2.0 -lgimpconfig-2.0 -lgimpcolor-2.0 -lgimpbase-2.0 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0   
/usr/bin/ld: lnoise_3d.o: undefined reference to symbol 'floor@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [felimage-noise] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `-lm` to the commandline.

```
cd src    
gcc  -g -O2 -Wall   -o felimage-noise  basis.o cell_3d.o cell_4d.o cell_5d.o \
 interface.o lnoise_3d.o lnoise_4d.o lnoise_5d.o loadconf.o main.o poisson.o random.o \
 render.o saveconf.o snoise_3d.o snoise_4d.o snoise_5d.o -lgimpui-2.0 -lgimpwidgets-2.0 \
-lgimpmodule-2.0 -lgimp-2.0 -lgimpmath-2.0 -lgimpconfig-2.0 -lgimpcolor-2.0 \
-lgimpbase-2.0 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 \
-lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig \
-lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0   -lm 
cd ..
```

sudo make install

Answer (score 3):

You can also edit the /src/Makefile adding `-lm` to the line where libraries are. I've done it with some other plugins and it worked like a charm.